# Creation of text files if they don't already exist

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I am trying to check if a text file exists and if not create it.
I have created a working multiple user login system via TkInter Python but require the code to be able to store data corresponding to the user logged in.
However I keep running into this error:

```
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\Python files\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 109, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\Python files\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\Python files\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\A Level Computer Science\programcodetest.py", line 92, in CheckLogin
    LoggedIn()
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\A Level Computer Science\programcodetest.py", line 137, in LoggedIn
    userfile = nameEL.get()
  File "D:\Python 3.3.2\Python files\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2512, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".44825680"`
```

This is the section of code encountering the error:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

creds = 'tempfile.txt'

def Signup():

    global pwordE
    global nameE
    global roots

    roots = Tk()
    roots.title('Signup')
    intruction = Label(roots, text='Please enter new Username and Password\n')
    intruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

    nameL = Label(roots, text='New Username: ')
    pwordL = Label(roots, text='New Password: ')
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    nameE = Entry(roots)
    pwordE = Entry(roots, show='*')
    nameE.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1)

    signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup)
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop()

def FSSignup():
    with open(creds, 'a') as f:
        f.write(nameE.get())
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(pwordE.get())
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()

    roots.destroy()
    Login()

def Login():

    global nameEL
    global pwordEL
    global rootA

    rootA = Tk()
    rootA.title('Login')

    intruction = Label(rootA, text='Please Login\n')
    intruction.grid(sticky=E)

    nameL = Label(rootA, text='Username: ')
    pwordL = Label(rootA, text='Password: ')
    nameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    pwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    nameEL = Entry(rootA)
    pwordEL = Entry(rootA, show='*')
    nameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    loginB = Button(rootA, text='Login', command=CheckLogin)
    loginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    adduser = Button(rootA, text='Add new user?', command=Signup)
    adduser.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    rmuser = Button(rootA, text='Delete Users', fg='red', command=Deluser)
    rmuser.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

def CheckLogin():

    global nameEL
    global pwordEL
    global rootA

    with open(creds) as f:
        try:
            data = f.read().splitlines()
            userloc = data.index(nameEL.get())
            pwordloc = data.index(pwordEL.get())
            if nameEL.get() in data:
                if pwordloc == userloc + 1:
                    r = Tk()
                    r.title('Login')
                    r.geometry('150x50')
                    rlbl = Label(r, text='\n Logged In')
                    rlbl.pack()
                    r.destroy()
                    LoggedIn()
                else:
                    rootA.destroy()
                    r = Tk()
                    r.title('Login')
                    r.geometry('150x50')
                    rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
                    rlbl.pack()
                    r.mainloop()
                    Login()
            else:
                rootA.destroy()
                r = Tk()
                r.title('Login')
                r.geometry('150x50')
                rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
                rlbl.pack()
                r.mainloop()
                Login()
        except ValueError:
            rootA.destroy()
            r = Tk()
            r.title('Login')
            r.geometry('150x50')
            rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
            rlbl.pack()
            r.mainloop()
            Login()

def Deluser():
    os.remove(creds)
    rootA.destroy()
    Signup()

def LoggedIn():

    global nameEL
    global pwordEL
    global rootA

    rootA.destroy()
    roots1 = Tk()
    roots1.title('Logged in successfully')
    roots1.geometry("300x300")

    userfile = nameEL.get()
    newuserfile = open(nameEL.get(),".txt", "a")
    #this is where I would like to check the existence of a text file under the current user and if it does not exist create one

if os.path.isfile(creds):
    Login()
else:
    Signup()
```

I would appreciate any suggestions and help :)

Comment: I'd recommend using a database to store user data instead of a text file... What's the point of having a login for security if the usernames and passwords are in a file on the computer?

Comment: Please show the full and complete error message, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note: that does not mean we want your whole program -- just enough code to illustrate the problem and nothing else.

Comment: I removed a fair bit of the code but realised that a lot of it is required for the next stage to make sense... I have also posted the whole of the error message above, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open(nameEL.get() + ".txt", "a")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'a' option to automatically create a file if the name specified does not exist:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: I have made this change to the code but am still getting the same error message ?

Comment: I would try putting this code in LoggedIn() in place of userfile and delete the if and else statements. That would just open the file, or if it does not exist, create it.

Comment: I'm having issues with assigning the names to the new text files as I'm trying to use the input for the names given to log in. I keep getting an error as mentioned above and believe it to be the use of .get() as a name for the text file. Is there any way I would be able to do this ?

Comment: The issue may be that .get() is returning a none type as the value stored in the dictionary. In this case, then a filename of none type would cause an error message. Also, you may need to pass a key to .get like this: .get(key). Check to make sure that you are storing what you think you are storing for key-value pairs in nameEL.

Comment: please could you explain how using the key to get the .get() would work as I am not familiar with it ?

Comment: .get() allows you to access the value stored in a dictionary by passing the key as a parameter to .get(). So, if we have a dictionary like this: dct = {"foo":10"} we can access the value by get: print dct.get("foo"), which will output 10. I think for your code, you need to take a closer look at pwordEL and nameEL and be sure they are storing what you want. Also, if you find this helpful, you could  support me by upvoting my answer above. I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: I can successfully print the strings stored under nameEL.get() and pwordEL.get() whilst in the CheckLogin function however cannot once passed onto the LoggedIn function... is there any reason why ?

Comment: I do not see anything being passed to the LoggedIn function, such as the data from the file creds in CheckLogin. I think your logic is that you read in the data in CheckLogin, and then it is available in LoggedIn. However, I think the issue is that your global variables declared in Login() are not being declared in LoggedIn. Try to declare the global variables nameEL, pwordEL, and rootA as global variables in LoggedIn.

Comment: I have tried declaring the global variables in the LoggedIn() function however am meeting the same error... why would I not have to declare these global variables in the CheckLogin() function as well ?

Comment: Actually, I believe I overlooked at part, you should put the global variables in any function which you will be using them.

Comment: Ive declared the global variables for nameEL, pwordEL and rootA in all the functions using them however am still getting the same error message. It successfully retrieves it when I print nameEL.get() within the CheckLogin function however gives an error when doing the same within the LoggedIn function ? Is there any reason why ?

Comment: Is the code posted the latest version? If so, you still need to declare nameEL, pwordEL, and rootA in LoggedIn(). If not, please post your latest code.

Comment: I have updated the code and the error message above and have added the global variables as you have suggested but still no luck...